# Differences and use of vuexpress, VuePress and vue-server-renderer modules of Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, static-site, vuepress

I came across [vuexpress](https://github.com/vuexpress/vuexpress), [vuepress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/) and [vue-server-renderer](https://ssr.vuejs.org/). To me these are looking somewhere similer which I guess are not. I am not frontend developer so not able to understand exact difference and use of these three modules.

Their official sites are saying

https://github.com/vuexpress/vuexpress

> vuexpress: Vue + Express.js = VueXpress / A server side rendering
>   engine for Express.js. Use .vue files as your express.js templates.

https://vuepress.vuejs.org/

> VuePress: Vue-powered Static Site Generator

https://ssr.vuejs.org/

> vue-server-renderer: server-rendered Single-Page Applications using
>   Node.js as the server.

vuepress and vue-server-renderer are official library from [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)

So what exactly are differences and use of these three modules?

Answer (score 2):

The idea with Vue (from the perspective of your question) is that you create a single-page application.

`vuexpress` is a rendering engine you can use in an Express application if you want to use the Vue syntax to implement your Express views, i.e. you implement a dynamic website and use the Vue syntax.

`vuepress` is about building a single-page application in Vue that also prerenders each page (and some other goodies, such as using markdown) to improve initial page load and facilitate for search engines. It is primarily used for websites with static content, such as documentation.

The point with a Vue application is to run it on the client (in the web browser). With `vue-server-renderer` you can run it on the server to obtain the HTML code the web browser would render if it would run in the web browser, and send it to the web browser, so the web browser doesn't need to run your Vue application, but receives the HTML it would display instead. Why? To improve initial page load and facilitate for search engines. I imagine `vuepress` makes use of `vue-server-renderer` under the hood.